# Angular-js:ng-click is not working

Tags: angularjs

as I am very new to angular js so I am trying to develop small app but I have got stuck because ng-click is not working it seems. Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:
HTML file:

```
    <html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <title>Angular Demo App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
        <h1>My Calculator</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input1"></input>
        <span ng-bind="this.selectedOperation"></span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input2"></input>
        <button ng-click="ctrl.computeResult()">=</button>
        <span ng-bind="ctrl.resultValue"></span>
        <p>Choose the operation:
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('+')">+</button>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('-')">-</button>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('*')">*</button>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('/')">/</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the controller:

```
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl() {

    this.buttonClicked = function (button) {
        this.selectedOperation = "button";
    }
    this.computeResult = function () {
        var num1 = parseFloat(this.input1);
        var num2 = parseFloat(this.input2);

        if (selectedOperation === "+") {
            this.resultValue = num1 + num2;
        } else if (selectedOperation === "-") {
            this.resultValue = num1 - num2;
        } else if (selectedOperation === "*") {
            this.resultValue = num1 * num2;
        } else if (selectedOperation === "/") {
            this.resultValue = num1 / num2;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, describe more precisely your problem.

Comment: Hi Alex, the main problem is my buttons are not working, when I click '+' button, ideally it should get reflected on the screen but I am not able to see this on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **`this.selectedOperation`** instead of **`selectedOperation`**

```
if (this.selectedOperation === "+") {
  this.resultValue = num1 + num2;
}
```

also your function should assign the parameter,

```
 this.buttonClicked = function (button) {
        this.selectedOperation = button;
    }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
app.controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);
function MyCtrl() {
   
    this.buttonClicked = function (button) {
        this.selectedOperation = button;
    }
    this.computeResult = function () {
        var num1 = parseFloat(this.input1);
        var num2 = parseFloat(this.input2);
        if (this.selectedOperation === "+") {
            this.resultValue = num1 + num2;
        } else if (this.selectedOperation === "-") {
            this.resultValue = num1 - num2;
        } else if (this.selectedOperation === "*") {
            this.resultValue = num1 * num2;
        } else if (this.selectedOperation === "/") {
            this.resultValue = num1 / num2;
        }

    }

}
```

```html
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Demo App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
        <h1>My Calculator</h1>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input1">
        <span ng-bind="ctrl.selectedOperation"></span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input2">
        <button ng-click="ctrl.computeResult()">=</button>
        <span ng-bind="ctrl.resultValue"></span>
        <p>Choose the operation:
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('+')">+</button>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('-')">-</button>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('*')">*</button>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('/')">/</button>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks Sajeetharan, but the buttons which I have used for operations itself are not working, when I click '+' button , I am not able to see on the screen.

Comment: where do you want to see?

Comment: Ideally, what should happen is when I click '+' button then buttonClicked method should be invoked and there selectedOperation property should be set as '+' and it should be reflected in span tag (as I have used ng-bind )which is written in html file but its not happening I guess.

Comment: you should use  <span ng-bind="ctrl.selectedOperation"></span> . check the updated demo. mark as answer if it helped

Comment: I got this error this time: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]. still facing the same issue

Comment: @Shivam that error is related to you trying to use a module that you have not properly injected. Look at angularjs injections.